# How to request data with token authorization in custom functions in Office JS Excel-Add-In?

Tags: excel, office-js

**What I have:**

I adapted [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial-create-custom-functions?tabs=excel-windows#create-a-custom-function-that-requests-data-from-the-web) example from Microsoft docs.

```
// functions.js

/**
 * Get data
 * @customfunction
 *  @returns {string[][]}
 */
async function getData() {
  try {
    const url = "https://api.example.com/some/objects/";
    const token = await OfficeRuntime.storage.getItem("Token");
    const authString = `Token ${token.toString()}`;
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      headers: { Authorization: authString }
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    const jsonResponse = await response.json();

    return jsonResponse.map(obj => {return [obj.id.toString(), obj.name]};
  } catch (error) {
    return [["ERROR", error.message]];
  }
}
```

- Added `api.example.com` to `<AppDomains>`
- `Item "Token"` is present in `OfficeRuntime.storage`
- Same API call with Postman works fine
- The Add-In is not served from localhost (because of CORS reasons etc.)

**What I get:**

Because it is not developed locally it is very hard to debug ui-less custom functions. Therefore the only visible error I get so far, is the one I receive and return to Excel in the catch-block. It is an unhelpful error message: `Network request failed`

Can anyone help me with any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason why it did not work was a known issue that custom functions run in a separate JavaScript runtime as described [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/558#issuecomment-502157016). This runtime allows only CORS-safelisted request header because it lacks of CORS-Preflight -> therefore the `Network request failed` error with the `Authorization` header.

How I solved it:

1. Configure the Excel-Add-in to use a shared JavaScript runtime as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/configure-your-add-in-to-use-a-shared-runtime).
2. Add `<script src="functions.js"></script>` just before the `<\head>` element in `taskpane.html` as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/share-data-and-events-between-custom-functions-and-the-task-pane-tutorial#create-task-pane-controls-to-work-with-global-data).
3. Build the project `npm run build`
4. Clear the cache as described in the first two steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache#clear-the-office-cache-on-windows).

Run Excel and load your Add-in.